# ¿Cómo hago notar un punto en particular en una gráfica de dispersión?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Tengo la siguiente gráfica de dispersión

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero destacar el nombre de México, que sea más grande que los otros. Sin embargo no puedo. Sin embargo, no sólo en esta gráfica si no también en otras de dispersión me gustaría hacerlo.

He intentado con `geom_label_repel` de la paquetería `ggrepel`, pero no puedo estructurar el código.

Answer (score 2):

Supongamos un gráfico como este:

```
library(ggplot)
library(ggrepel)

dat <- subset(mtcars, wt > 2.75 & wt < 3.45)
dat$car <- rownames(dat)

ggplot(dat, aes(wt, mpg, label = car)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_label_repel()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Usamos `geom_label_repel()` por que significa una mejora significativa con respecto al `geom_text()` pero la forma de destacar uno o más puntos es consistente con ambas funciones.

Básicamente lo que necesitamos es definir una nueva dimensión estética (`aes`) para `ggplot` que especifique el criterio de lo que queremos destacar. Supongamos que queremos destacar el modelo `Hornet 4 Drive` del resto. Lo primero que debemos hacer es crear una columna nueva que señale el punto de interés, eventualmente se podría manejar en otro vector, pero es mucho más cómodo hacerlo así:

```
dat$is_hornet <- factor(ifelse(dat$car == "Hornet 4 Drive", 1, 0))
```

El modelo, o el punto que sea `Hornet 4 Drive` tendrá `is_hornet == 1`, esto nos da una nueva dimensión que podremos "mapear" a un `color`, `size`, `shape` y alguna otra dimensión más que dependerá del `geom` usado:

```
dat$is_hornet <- factor(ifelse(dat$car == "Hornet 4 Drive", 1, 0))
ggplot(dat, aes(wt, mpg, label = car, 
                color = is_hornet,
                size = is_hornet)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_label_repel() +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

Hemos "mapeado" dos dimensiones estéticas `color` y `size` a la variable `is_hornet`, ten en cuenta que esto por defecto incorpora leyendas con estas dimensiones, como en este caso no tienen mucho sentido, hemos agregado `theme(legend.position = "none")` para queitarlas.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]